# Running python script from crontab on OSX?

Tags: python, macos, cron

I do have experience with crontab, but this is first time using it on OSX 10.15.
Have this strange error:

```
    Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 980, in exec_module
  File "<frozen site>", line 616, in <module>
  File "<frozen site>", line 599, in main
  File "<frozen site>", line 517, in venv
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/macbook/code/script/venv_3-11-4/pyvenv.cfg'
```

file pyvenv.cfg exist

```
-rw-r--r--  1 macbook  staff  307 Jun 26 11:50 venv_3-11-4/pyvenv.cfg
```

Any ideas why ?

Comment: Insufficient information. Python version? The crontab entry? Are you using the `macbook` users's crontab or root or some other user? The minimal Python program that results in the error?

Comment: @KurtisRader problem is that cron does not have Full Disk Access in OSX. At least on OSX 10.15 that I use. I will post answer bellow. Anyway I will go back to Linux for next install.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Apple menu in the top-left corner of your screen and select "System Preferences".

In the System Preferences window, click on "Security & Privacy".

Switch to the "Privacy" tab.

Scroll down in the left sidebar and select "Full Disk Access".

Click on the lock icon in the bottom-left corner of the window and enter your administrator password when prompted. This will allow you to make changes to the privacy settings.

Click on the "+" (plus) button below the list of applications and utilities.

In the file browser that appears, press Command + Shift + G. This keyboard shortcut will bring up a "Go to Folder" window.

In the "Go to Folder" window, enter "/usr/sbin/" and click "Go".

Locate and select the "cron" file in the "/usr/sbin/" directory.

Click "Open" to add cron to the list of applications with Full Disk Access.

You should now see "cron" listed in the Full Disk Access window.